# Odoo JS / Changes in one2many field (tree) appears only after reloading the page

Tags: javascript, odoo

I am a beginner Odoo developer, I have a little issue with my code which is I change a field called "state" in a One2many field appointment_ids (tree), it changes, but it looks the same and the change appears only after I reload the page or click any other button and return.

the codes I am using :
The wizard used to return the form view :

```
class choose_appointment_customer(models.TransientModel):
_name = "choose.appointment.customer"

@api.model
    def action_finish_scheduling(self, args):
// some code here that call _return_action_appointments function but it's long and it's working fine 
return self._return_action_appointments(appointment_ids, batch_id)

@api.model
    def _return_action_appointments(self, appointment_ids, batch_id):
        """
        Method to return proper actions for those appointment_ids

        Args:
         * appointment_ids - business_appointment recordset

        Returns:
         * ir.act.window dict
        """
        res = False
        if len(appointment_ids) >= 1:
            res = self.sudo().env.ref("slnee_appointment_core.business_appointment_batch_action_only_form").read()[0]
            res["res_id"] = appointment_ids[0].batch_id.id
        return res
```

XML:

```
<record id="business_appointment_batch_action_only_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Appointment</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">business.appointment.batch</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    </record>
```

the js function executed to return the form view:

```
/**
     *   Re-write to make chosen appointments + close parent dialog + open form view
    */
    _save: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.form_view.saveRecord(self.form_view.handle, {
            stayInEdit: true,
            reload: false,
            savePoint: self.shouldSaveLocally,
            viewType: 'form',
        }).then(function (changedFields) {
            var record =  self.form_view.model.get(self.form_view.handle, {raw: true})
            var chosenAppointments = self.parentRenderer.chosenAppointments;
            self._rpc({
                model: "choose.appointment.customer",
                method: "action_finish_scheduling",
                args: [{"data": record.data, "chosen": chosenAppointments}],
                context: record.context,
            }).then(function (res) {
                self.close();
                self.topWindow.closeCalc(res);
            });

        });
    },


});
```

The One2many field I am talking about (model : business.appointment ) :

```
<!--    Form View    -->
    <record id="business_appointment_batch_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">business.appointment.batch.form</field>
        <field name="model">business.appointment.batch</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form js_class="ba_batch_form">
<page string="Reservations">
                            <field name="appointment_ids" readonly="1"
                                   options="{'no_create_edit': 1, 'no_quick_create': 1,'no_open':True,'no_create' :1}"
                            widget="one2many_selection">
                                <tree default_order="datetime_start"
                                      decoration-success="state in ['done']"
                                      decoration-muted="state in ['cancel']"
                                      decoration-warning="state in ['missed']"
                                >
                                    <field name="hide_delete_button" invisible="1"/>
                                    <field name="is_pack" invisible="1"/>
                                    <field name="resource_id"/>
                                    <field name="service_id"/>
                                    <field name="datetime_start"/>
                                    <field name="datetime_end"/>
                                    <field name="state"/>
                                    <button name="open_this" type="object" icon="fa-list"/>
                                    <button name="%(base_cancel_reason.base_cancel_reason_wizard_action)d" type="action"
                                            icon="fa-trash"
                                            attrs="{'invisible': ['|','|',('hide_delete_button', '=', True),('state', 'in', ['cancel', 'missed', 'done']),('parent.state', '!=', 'reserved')]}"
                                    />
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </page>
```

Please help me and thank you in advance.

I tried crnd_web_view_refresh_timed module in Odoo apps store but it did not reload the tree view "appointment_ids"

Comment: As per my search, I think I need to refresh the list controller of the one2many field "appointment_ids" or the whole form controller.